# On the binomial coefficient $\binom{-1}{-1}$

Tags: combinatorics, complex-analysis, analysis, binomial-coefficients, special-functions

Someone submitted a new entry (entitled "[Don Knuth Plays with ChatGPT](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=36012360)") to Hacker News a few hours ago. The entry pointed to a [text file](https://cs.stanford.edu/%7Eknuth/chatGPT20.txt) that documented twenty questions posed to ChatGPT, the answers returned as well as Donald Knuth's comments. Question 3 is as follows:

> Why does Mathematica give the wrong value for Binomial[-1,-1]?

ChatGPT answered that

> The expression Binomial[-1,-1] is undefined, and so there is no unique
> or "correct" value that can be assigned to it. ... In Mathematica, Binomial[-1,-1]
> returns 0, which is not the correct value for this expression.

Knuth commented that (emphasis mine):

> Answer #3 is fouled up beautifully! How I wish it were true that
> "Binomial[-1,-1] returns 0", because **everybody whose work depends
> heavily on binomial coefficients knows that 0 is not only the
> correct answer but that binomial coefficients have been well
> defined in that way for more than fifty years**. And of course,
> unfortunately, Binomial[-1,-1] actually returns 1, alas.
>
> The answer goes on to state that (-1)! is well defined (indeed
> equal to 1), etc. But it's all expressed in marvelous English prose.

Why should $\binom{-1}{-1}$ be defined as zero? Is it a convenient convention (if so, why is it convenient?) or is there a proper generalization of $\binom{n}{k}$ to negative arguments that evaluates to $0$ when $n=k=-1$? I thought that
$$\binom{n}{k}=\frac{\Gamma(n+1)}{\Gamma(k+1)\Gamma(n-k+1)}$$
when both the numerator and denominator are well-defined. When $n=k=-1$, although the gamma function is not defined at zero, if we cancel out the two instances of $\Gamma(0)$ in the numerator and denominator, isn't it more sensible to define $\binom{-1}{-1}$ as $\frac{1}{\Gamma(1)}=1$?

Comment: From the perspective of combinatorics and algebra (where binomial coefficients have *meaning*), one should have $\binom{n}{k} = 0$ whenever $k$ is anything other than a nonnegative integer.

Comment: @JBL Would you care to explain?

Comment: For nonnegative integer $n$ the binomial coefficient counts subsets by size, so of course you should get $0$ unless the size is a nonnegative integer.  For negative integer $n$ it counts multisets by size, same story.  But more generally $\binom{n}{k}$ is the coefficient of $z^k$ in the power series expansion of $(1 + z)^n$ around $z = 0$ (where $n$ can be any kind of thing you want -- an integer, a real number, a complex number, a variable) and the only terms that ever appear in such an expansion are for $k$ a nonnegative integer.

Comment: There's still an analogue using the Gamma function, but that leaves some questions lingering about what you have to do when you would end up evaluating a negative integer factorial (i.e. when $n$, $k$, or $n-k$ is a negative integer), since then you encounter a pole of the Gamma function. That said, see https://mathworld.wolfram.com/BinomialCoefficient.html ... these issues have been sorted out to the extent that they can be. But I don't think I've seen a use for binomial coefficients ${n \choose k}$ when $k$ isn't a nonnegative integer.

Comment: I can't say what people outside of algebra and combinatorics do, but inside the field there is no use for a gamma function extension of binomial coefficients to $k$ outside $\mathbb{N}$ because they don't mean anything.  (See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4697345/what-is-the-combinatorial-meaning-of-binomn-frac1k )

Comment: Coincidentally, the answer given by ChatGPT need not be interpreted as saying $(-1)!=1$, as the comments you posted imply.  It could also be interpreted as saying $(-1)! = 1/0$ (and $0!=1$) which is perfectly sound nonsense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For combinatorics, the appropriate context to talk about $\binom{n}{k}$ is generating functions, not meromorphic functions.  This shouldn't be surprising that there are different ways to extend a concept.

In this context, $\binom{n}{k}$ is the coefficient of $z^k$ of $(1+z)^n \in \mathbb{R}[[x]]$.

Here, $n$ may be any real number, but definitionally any $k$ which isn't a non-negative integer would result in $0$.

Comment: In fact $n$ can be things other than real numbers, too.  For example, in the context of Stirling numbers and enumerating cycles in permutations, one might like to consider the two-variable generating function $(1 + z)^t$ in $\mathbb{Z}[t][[z]]$, whose coefficient of $z^k$ is precisely $\binom{t}{k} = \frac{t(t - 1) \cdots (t - k + 1)}{k!}$, a polynomial in the formal variable $t$ of degree $k$.

Comment: Uh of course that should be $\mathbb{Q}[t]$, not $\mathbb{Z}[t]$.